# Post nested array to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I post multidimensional array with form to Rails?

I tried to generate following html:

```
<input type="text" name="bounds[0][]" value="">
<input type="text" name="bounds[0][]" value="">
```

And expected to get nested Array in params Hash:

```
{"bounds"=>[["30.201416", "50.597186"], ["30.860596", "50.590212"]]}
```

But instead Rails parses it as Hash with Stringified keys:

```
{"bounds"=>{"0"=>["30.201416", "50.597186"], "1"=>["30.860596", "50.590212"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `controllers`, you should read it like `bounds[][]`.

When you want to display,  you should make a `loop`. Try

```
<% bounds.each do |bound| %>
  <%= bound %>
<% end %>
```